# .NetCore 3.1API Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions'

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

I am using aws to deploy my project to server(.NetCore 3.1). I am getting above error.But in local iis working fine.

I tried to install 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions'. But still I am facing same issue.

Please find below for package reference

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.4.1" />
    
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Helpers\Helpers.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Models\Models.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Repository\Repository.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Services\Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

I have gone through few [link](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2194) regarding same error. I tried all the method. But still i am getting same issue.

Comment: Guys someone please help me out

Comment: Have you installed the latest  webhosting bundle in AWS?

Comment: @JokiesDing I am not sure because i am not handling this server. But i extracted the dll then i came to know in server there is no latest version of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions' (Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60) but in my local (Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60). Hopefully i am thinking that there is no latest version is present in server

Comment: It sounds like the .net core version on AWS is .net core 2.2. So have you installed 3.1 and hosting bundle on that AWS server?

Comment: Yes in server 3.1 is present.

Comment: ` .NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.105 [C:\Program Files..]
  2.2.110 [C:\Program Files..]
.NET Core runtimes installed:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files..l]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files..]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files..]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files..]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files..]`

Comment: Could you get it work with out-process by including dll inside your project?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Ya sure @JokiesDing. I have a doubt. I am using one api project and four class library. Do i need to add this for all five

Comment: Why aren’t you referencing the missing assembly in your csproj exactly? When you do dot net publish using cli, what assemblies do you see in output?

Comment: @jbooker While publish from local and hosted in iis everything working fine. But in AWS publish throwing this error.

Comment: Can you answer my questions exactly?

Comment: The error message is pretty indicative of the issue. If you follow my questions, I think youll find your solution..

Comment: @jbooker Usually assembly’s will generate which we have indicate in csproj as well as other than few assembly’s will generate. Yes i found the issue Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstraction is showing 2.2.0.. which generating in aws and few more things also generating 2.2.0. But in my local publish it showing assembly’s are generating in core versions that is 3.1.0. Something working in AWS config. I don’t have access to the AWS.

Comment: Did you try to publish and look out the output directory for which binaries were included? If not, then its almost impossible for me to help you if we dont walk through that process. Instead, Id recommend creating a minimum reproducible example and posting that to get some help.

Comment: How did you publish  the application? I think host out-process or install 3.1.0 would be a choice. Maybe you shouldfix it in project side by trying to specify assmebly in csproj since you can't access AWS.

Comment: Have you tried publishing your app as self-contained?

Comment: @JokiesDing  I tried out-process it’s not working

Comment: @JokiesDing I spoke to AWS admin. He told that he check and let me know about AWS config deployment file

Comment: Have you checked all embeded projects for missing assembly?

Answer (score 0):

This could be similar to this issue (different file) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/8017/aspnet-core-310-site-wont-run-could-not-load-micro.html

could you please verify all the .Net core related packages in all the projects? Also, if you can post the package reference from all your projects, it will be easy to verify.

The issue could be due to one or more packages in any of your projects. Also, make sure the correct version of SDK is available in AWS. Try an empty app with the same project setup (same packages in all the 5 projects with lower package version ) and deploy this to AWS to find out the issue.

Comment: For all 5 projects same package i have installed which i have posted. The issue is if i publish by my own and host in environment it’s working fine but if publish by pipeline it’s showing error. So i am bit confused.

Comment: Difference between compiling on Windows vs Linux maybe?